# Can input port be of type reg in verilog?

Tags: verilog

In my textbook there is a side note that input or inout ports can never be a reg, as this will result in perpetual 'x' in the port. However, when I wrote a code for AND gate with input ports set as reg types, it worked fine.

AND GATE:

```
//AND Gate

`timescale 1ns/100ps
module test(output C, input reg A,B);
assign C = A & B;
endmodule
```

Test Bench:

```
//AND GATE TEST BENCH
`timescale 1ns/100ps


module AND_tb;

//Declaring Variables
wire Cwatch;
reg [1:0] stim;

initial begin
#1 stim = 2'b00;
#1 stim = 2'b01;
#1 stim = 2'b10;
#1 stim = 2'b11;
#1 $stop;
end

test AND_1 (
.C(Cwatch),
.A(stim[0]), 
.B(stim[1])
);
endmodule
```

And here is the [paragraph from the textbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3QP9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not told which simulator you use.

But yes, I also noticed that some simulators have no problem with a input defined as 'reg'. I regard it as an idiosyncrasy of the simulator.

However as soon as you try to synthesize it is likely<sup>1</sup> to fail.

1: <sub>I have yet to find a synthesis tool which accepts  `input reg` it but I have not tried all existing ones.</sub>

Comment: I am using Mentor Graphics Modelsim student edition, sorry for not stating that earlier. I would appreciate if you could recommend any gate level synthesis software, as I have been searching for a while and have not found any.

Comment: I have not looked but I think you are unlikely to find any. Working with gates means you have to work with a silicon foundry and they do not give easy access to their libraries.